# from something to something to something

Tags: grammar

I've seen a few times such a structure of a sentence. For example:

> Analyzing the contribution margin helps managers make several types of decisions, **from** whether to add or subtract a product line **to** how to price a product or service **to** how to structure sales commissions.

Is it grammatical?

Comment: [This is exactly what you are looking for.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299547/why-are-there-two-tos-in-from-to-to)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is one type of structure for listing a few examples of something. "Students are considering many factors in choosing a university, from the price of tuition to the size of the dorm rooms to the reputation of the professors."